# Want to add a session idle timeout to an older AngularDart (v1.24.0 SDK) web application

Tags: dart, angular-dart, session-timeout

I have an AngularDart app created in 2016 that uses the dependencies listed below.  My client would like to add a session idle timeout to the application and I have not the first idea how to start.  It doesn't help that the application was created 4 years ago and is not on the current version.  Any suggestions on what dart or angulardart libraries might include components that would support this need?

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0+2
  angular_router: ^1.0.2
  angular_components: ^0.6.0
  json_object: any
  http: "^0.11.3+14"
  angular_dart_ui_bootstrap: '>=0.0.1'
  ng_bootstrap: ^0.9.2
  dartson: "^0.2.7"
  browser_detect: "^1.0.4"
  archive: "^1.0.33"
  build: "^0.11.0"
  intl: "^0.15.6"

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  test: ^0.12.0
  angular_test: ^1.0.0

transformers:
- dartson
- angular:
    entry_points:
      - web/main.dart
      - test/**_test.dart
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter

# Uncomment the following in sdk 1.24+ to make pub serve
# use dartdevc (webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc).
#web:
#  compiler:
#    debug: dartdevc
```

Edit:
I attempted to create a solution by adding a timer and trapping user interaction on the page.

In my app_component.dart I added event listeners in the init function.  I create a timer and set its timeout to one minute just to test.

There is a start event listener that creates the timer when called.  This is called the first time after the user successfully logs in.

There is a cancel event timer that cancels the timer, nulls it, and if the user is still logged in, re-creates the timer. This is called by user activity (keypress or mousemove), or by logout.  If the user is still logged in when this is called then the timer is canceled, set null, and created again.  If the user is logged out, it is not re-created.

The point of this code is to begin the timer when the user logs in, restart it whenever the user interacts with the app (keypress or mousemove), and turn it off when the user is logged out.

It is intended that if there is no user activity for 1 minute, then the handleTimerEvent will be called.  This is close to working by I have unexpected behavior.

```
      Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {

        _eventService.onStartIdleTimer.stream.listen((timerEvent) {
          if(idleTimer == null) {
            print(
                "Starting idleTimer: " + new DateTime.now().toLocal().toString());
            idleTimerStarted = new DateTime.now();
            idleTimer = new Timer(new Duration(minutes: 1), handleTimerEvent());
          }
        });

        _eventService.onCancelIdleTimer.stream.listen((timerEvent){
          if(idleTimer != null) {
            if (idleTimer.isActive) {
              print(
                  "Canceling idleTimer: " +
                      new DateTime.now().toLocal().toString());
              var diff = new DateTime.now().difference(idleTimerStarted);
              print(diff.inSeconds.toString() +" seconds elapsed.");

              idleTimer.cancel();
              idleTimer = null;
              if (isLoggedIn)
                _eventService.onStartIdleTimer.add(new IdleTimerEvent("Start"));
            }
          }
        });
  }

  handleTimerEvent(){
    print("In handleTimerEvent!");
    if(this.isLoggedIn){
      if(new DateTime.now().difference(idleTimerStarted).inMinutes > 1){
        print("Idle Timer passed configured limit.  Logging user out.");
        logoutForIdle();
      } else {
        _eventService.onStartIdleTimer.add(new IdleTimerEvent("Start"));
      }
    }
  }

  logoutForIdle() {
    _eventService.onError.add(new GenomicsErrorEvent()
      ..message = globals.idleTimeoutMessage
      ..dismissable = true
      ..alertType = alertType);

    logout();

    _eventService.onCancelIdleTimer.add(new IdleTimerEvent("Cancel"));
  }
```

First of all, when I call Timer.cancel(), the callback seems to be firing, which is unexpected.  And when I wait for the timeout, i get this exception:

```
EXCEPTION: NullError: method not found: 'call$0' on null
STACKTRACE: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call$0' of null
    at StaticClosure.dart._rootRun (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:7427:18)
    at _ZoneDelegate.run$2 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:10632:41)
    at NgZone.dart.NgZone._run$4 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:112512:24)
    at Object.eval (eval at Closure_forwardCallTo (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:4663:14), <anonymous>:3:45)
    at _CustomZone.run$1 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:10765:41)
    at _CustomZone.runGuarded$1 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:10681:21)
    at _CustomZone_bindCallback_closure.dart._CustomZone_bindCallback_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:10836:27)
    at NgZone__createTimer_closure.dart.NgZone__createTimer_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:112664:19)
    at StaticClosure.dart._rootRun (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:7432:16)
    at _ZoneDelegate.run$2 (http://localhost:63114/main.dart.js:10632:41)
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: NullError: method not found: 'call$0' on null
```

I am very confused.

Solved by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
idleTimer = new Timer(new Duration(minutes: 1), handleTimerEvent());
```

Should be

```
idleTimer = new Timer(new Duration(minutes: 1), handleTimerEvent);
```

The code you wrote is *calling* `handleTimerEvent` when it creates the timer, and passing `null` (the implicit return value from `handleTimerEvent()`) as the callback to the timer. You are calling it instead of passing it as a callback, that is why it is running. When the timer fires it tries to call `null` as a function which is the exception you see. It's not clear why the cancel isn't working - perhaps things are running in the wrong order and you are attempting to cancel before starting the timer.

Comment: Side note: This is one of the reasons it helps to specify return types. If you had written `void handleTimerEvent() {...` instead of leaving off the return type (which gives an implicit `dynamic` return type) then `dartanalyzer` would be able to help you find this mistake.

Comment: OMG...facepalm.  Testing.

Comment: Yep, that was in.  Needed a bit more tweaking but that solved it, Thank you!